# Firebase how to export my index file after changing to import instead of requires?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express

I'm trying to convert from using requires and use only import to stay consistent throughout my code. While doing this I had to add `"type": "module"` and this caused a few issues but I resolved all them but one. I was orginally using `exports.expressApi = functions.https.onRequest(app)` however it is no longer accepting exports when I try to run Firebase deploy. So I tried to change the line to the code below but I am still unable to deploy.

```
const expressApi = functions.https.onRequest(app)
export default expressApi
```

Anyone have any suggestions on what may be causing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

could you try `module.exports = { expressApi }` or `export {expressApi}` instead of `export default expressApi`. Because I'm not sure how Cloud Functions react to a default export.

Comment: I resolved the issue. It turned out that for some reason a firebase dependency got removed from my package for some reason.

Comment: Well, that's great. To help others that encounter this issue in the future, you would do them a great service if you were to make a post about how you solved it. Then, you could change this question's status to solved.